# navigating through pages after hiding section in fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

I'm currently using fullPage.js (http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) for my app. 
I would like to hide and show pages based on the checkbox selected. Contents should show if checkbox is checked, and hidden if unchecked. The issue I'm having now is that if `content#1` is unchecked, the page will show content from `firstPage` but have `secondPage` in url because its not finding contents for `secondPage`, then `thirdPage` and `fourthPage` would show as I go down the page. Is there a way skip through the pages that are `hidden`?

```
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" data-target=".target1" checked/> Checkbox 1
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" data-target=".target2" checked/> Checkbox 2

<!-- firstPage -->
<div class="section">
  <p>
  Content on Page 1
  </p>
</div> 

<!-- secondPage -->
<div class="section target1">
  <p>
  show content #1 
  Content on Page 2
  </p>
</div>
<!-- thridPage -->
<div class="section target2">
  <p>
  show content #2
  Content on Page 3
  </p>
</div>
<!-- fourthPage -->
<div class="section target2">
  <p>
  Content on Page 4
  </p>
</div>

<script>
  $('.checkbox').change(function () {
    var target = $(this).data("target");
    $(target).toggle("show");
  });
<script>
```

I've also tried to removing the class for `secondPage` if $(this) is not checked. The issue with this is that I won't be able to navigate pass `firstPage`.

```
  $('.constraint_entry').change(function () {
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
      $(target).addClass('fp-section');
    }
    else{
      $(target).removeClass('fp-section');
    }
  });
```

JS Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/U93aE/399/